# how to use mac address in android app program

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi

I m new to android development i want to use mac address for unique.. my mac address is like
ad:db:08:23:04... how this address will use in this code.. where i will kept this address in this.. is this code is correct or i want to change anything.. please sir try to help me how i will work on this

```
  WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
  WifiInfo info =   manager.getConnectionInfo(); 
  String address = info.getMacAddress();
```

Comment: check this link, it may help: http://programminglinuxblog.blogspot.pt/2011/06/mac-address-string-to-byte.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this permission in Manifest file for your code to work -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: haa sir i addedd permission also but not working.. how to check that mac id.... my mac id is ad:0g:00:6f something sir.. tell me how to use that address of mac in tht code.. try to give me full code sir

Comment: sometimes it doesn't work when wifi is off. check by turning on your device wifi